# Why the HTML file opened, it is blank?

Tags: python, selenium

I write a python program in pycharm, using Selenium to log in Facebook and get a page content, then write the page content (html_user_page) in a file(.html), when the program run, the file has been already created and the html has been written in this file.

However, when open the .html file using IE, Firefox and Chrome, the page is blank (the color is all black, no any content), maybe it is related to encode method?

```
login_url = "https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1&lwv=110"
glovar.webdriver_browser = webdriver.Chrome()
glovar.webdriver_browser.get(login_url)

# user credentials
user = glovar.webdriver_browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#email")
user.send_keys('********@gmail.com')
password = glovar.webdriver_browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#pass")
password.send_keys('********')
login = glovar.webdriver_browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#loginbutton")
login.click()
glovar.webdriver_browser.get("********")
html_user_page = glovar.webdriver_browser.page_source
html_file = open(os.path.join(file_directory,type+"_"+user_addr_name+".html"),"w",encoding='utf-8')
html_file.write(html_user_page)
html_file.close()
```

Comment: Please, provide the content of your `.html` file

Comment: Do you get any output with `print html_user_page`?

Comment: when run "pritn(html_user_page)"， there are output, it seems a html file content

Comment: the content of .html file:

Comment: the .html file is too large to post here,could you please tell me how to upload the .html file ,or you could give me youe communication method, I can send the .html file to you